# Error with ansible backslash in replace

Tags: ansible

I am trying to replace a pattern with a string containing a backslash

```
- name: Replace test
       replace: dest=/tmp/test
       regexp="test"
       replace="test, \"
```

I get the following error in ansible:

```
 The error appears to have been in '/home/deployer/ansible/roles/test/tasks/configuration.yml': line 11, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Replace test
  ^ here
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact, that you've omitted the actual error message starting with word `ERROR!`, here is the fix for your problem:

```
- name: Replace test
  replace:
    dest: /tmp/test
    regexp: test
    replace: 'test, \\'
```

- mind the indentation
- use dict-style syntax for complex string manipulation (not `param=value` shorthand)
- escape slash in regexp-replace expression

Answer (score 1):

Another easy solution is to leave escaping backslash to ansible itself. This is how i would have done.

```
- set_fact:
    replacer: '\'

- name: Replace test
  replace:
    dest: /tmp/test
    regexp: test
    replace: 'test, replacer'
```